# R paste string with collapse - How to keep string with quotes?

Tags: r, paste

I have a problem with the quotes in pasting two strings together.

I want an output like this: query= "sql query","port"

I tried:

```
      query<-c("sql query","port")
      paste(queryString,collapse=",")
```

which gives:"sql query,port"

Also tried this:

```
        query<-c("sql query")
        query<-paste(query,"port",sep=",")
```

which also gives: "sql query,port"

Without the quotes in the right place the query won't run.
How can I keep them ?

Comment: Updated with some benchmarks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
queryq <- toString(shQuote(query))
```

which gives:

```
cat(queryq, "\n")
## "sql query", "port"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use

```
toString(sprintf("'%s'", query))
#[1] "'sql query', 'port'"
```

#### Benchmarks

Created some random strings using `stri_rand_strings` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
n <- 1e6
set.seed(25)
query1 <-  stri_rand_strings(n, 6, '[A-Za-z]')

f1 <- function() {toString(sprintf("'%s'", query1)) }
f2 <- function() {toString(shQuote(query1))}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq    mean   median      uq      max neval cld
#f1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000    20  a 
#f2() 1.557221 1.488862 1.43024 1.443488 1.36958 1.362173    20   b
```